# In Android how do I upload something to an anonymous Dropbox File Request?

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

The Dropbox Android SDK supports uploading a file to the user's Dropbox account through the `DropboxAPI.UploadRequest` API. However, this API requires a valid `Session` object, meaning it is only meant to be used to modify files of the logged in user. But Dropbox also supports [anonymous file requests](https://www.dropbox.com/help/9090) which allow anybody, even non Dropbox users, to upload files to a directory.

How can I upload a content to these Dropbox file requests without requiring the user to have a Dropbox account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox File Requests feature doesn't require end-users to have a Dropbox account to submit files via the web site, however Dropbox doesn't offer a programmatic interface for doing so. We'll consider this a feature request for one though.

Comment: I should say that in general, I'm looking for a way to upload files to my own account without giving apps the ability to have full read / write access to all of my files.  If you can solve that in another way I'd be fine with that